# Silverlight DataGrid's DataTemplate and Explicit UpdateSourceTrigger

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, binding, updatesourcetrigger

I want a Textbox in a DataGrid's DataTemplate to explicitly update when a user clicks the OK button.  I have the following XAML code:

```
<sdk:DataGrid ...>
  <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Series Name" Width="200" IsReadOnly="False">
     <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="labelData">
           <TextBox Text="{Binding Label, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" x:Name="colorPicker"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</sdk::DataGrid>
```

I set to UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit.  How do I access the TextBox items to call UpdateSource() on them?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/), this allows you to query the visual tree to find elements that match certain criteria. If you name your `DataGrid`, `x:Name="myGrid"`, the following should work:

```
var textBoxes = myGrid.Descendants<TextBox>().Cast<TextBox>();
foreach(var textbox in textBoxes)
{
    BindingExpression be = textbox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    be.UpdateSource();
}
```

However, you might find it simpler to move this functionality into a ViewModel.

Comment: Nice solution but I think I found another way of doing it without inheriting that API.  Basically I iterate through each column then "GetCellContent" of each item in the ItemsSource.